# Mounting SSH keys for SSL for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am setting up SSL for Postgres9.6 connections. I could not mount SSH private key and cert in a Kubernetes secret with appropriate permissions. I believe without any explicit user id set on the Kubernetes container, the mounted secret should be owned by root. I have set `416` decimal for octal `0640`. This is a recommendation from Postgres if files are owned by root.

Any help is appreciated.

Error:

```
 FATAL:  could not load private key file "/var/lib/postgresql/certs/server.key": Permission denied
```

Helm statefulset config:

```
  volumes:  
  - name: {{ .Values.certs_secret.volume_name }}
    secret:
      secretName: {{ .Values.certs_secret.secret_name }}
      items:
      - key: server.key
        path: server.key
        mode: 416  
      - key: server.crt
        path: server.crt
        mode: 511 
  containers:
  - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    args: 
      - -c
      - ssl=on
      - -c
      - ssl_cert_file={{ .Values.certs_secret.cert_path }}
      - -c
      - ssl_key_file={{ .Values.certs_secret.private_key_path }}
    volumeMounts:
    - name: {{ .Values.certs_secret.volume_name }}
      mountPath: {{ .Values.certs_secret.mount_path }}
```

**Updated**

I have exec'd in without turning SSL on and found secret files are mounted as symlinks. Could this be a problem? The cluster is in AKS.

```
root@postgres-timescale-db-0:/var/lib/postgresql/certs# find . -ls
        2      0 drwxrwxrwt   3 root     root          120 Oct 29 16:40 .
        8      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           31 Oct 29 16:40 ./..data -> ..2019_10_29_16_40_00.233198123
        7      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           17 Oct 29 16:40 ./server.crt -> ..data/server.crt
        6      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           17 Oct 29 16:40 ./server.key -> ..data/server.key
        3      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           80 Oct 29 16:40 ./..2019_10_29_16_40_00.233198123
        5      8 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root     root         4450 Oct 29 16:40 ./..2019_10_29_16_40_00.233198123/server.crt
        4      4 -rw-r-----   1 root     root         1679 Oct 29 16:40 ./..2019_10_29_16_40_00.233198123/server.key
```

Comment: The image used is postgres:9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what user does postgres run - root or something else? Some Docker images use `postgres` with `uid` of 999...

Without having the complete deployment configuration I'll suggest that, once you know the user, take a look at [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod) for how to configure `securityContext` to set the ownership of directories and files from mounted volumes.

Comment: cannot use securitycontext (setting user, groud ids) especially fist time as it hinders with creation of data folders. i believe postgres runs docker entrypoint files (create postgres user, data files with appropriate ownership and permissions) as root and then downgrades to postgres user

Comment: i have added long listing of files (/var/lib/postgresql/certs) to the original post. please let know if it has some clues.

Comment: "...found secret files are mounted as symlinks" - that's how files created from configMap-s and secrets appear, so it is "normal". I see you can get a shell in the container - could you get the user with which postgres runs? E.g. execute `ps -f` inside the container.

Comment: Here's why asked for the user: the server.key file has permissions set as 0640 - read+write for the root user and read for the root group; if postgres isn't running as root but as a different user, that user doesn't have permission to read the file. Setting the mode to 0644, or not setting it at all because that is the default for secrets, will allow that user to read the file. Yes, other users will also be able to read the file. That's why I was suggesting you to look into securityContext (fsGroup in particular) - it's worth trying to set it to the group of the postgres user, if it isn't root

Comment: Setting fsGroup and setting server.key to 416 and server.crt to 511 makes Postgres enable SSL for connections. Can be verified using `select * from pg_stat_ssl;`.